How to make an Azure DevOps branch policy pipeline which also performs a "simulated" merge build and test?
In addition to our current branch policy pipeline, which performs a build of the proposed branch to be merged and runs unit tests within build, I would like to add an extra step which then simulates the resultant merge before integration with main code. If the 2nd-level build and test also passes, then the PR should be able to be completed (post normal Peer/code review). As we currently have several occasions where bugs/test failures are only being picked up after merge.
Currently, the branch policy pipelines generally consist of the following tasks:

VSBuild / dotnetcore build of the proposed branch
VSTest / dotnetcore test of proposed branch

I believe the extra steps I'm looking for in the pipeline (after it's successfully performed the above tasks) is:

Create temporary branch (e.g. sim-merge) from the proposed branch to be merged
Merge with main (simulating the post PR merge state)
Perform a build on newly-merged sim-merge branch
Perform/Run unit tests on simulated merge build (if successfully built)

In future, we may want to add an additional step that takes the new "simulated" merge build and deploys it to a temp environment to run some additional (quick) automated integration/API tests. Again, all to add confidence to quality to (and reduce risk of breaking) the main branch.
Does anyone have any examples they can point to of a tried and tested pipeline config that could achieve something like this?
I tried searching online (and on this site) for existing pipelines, but all results that come back are for doing standard build validation. So I suspect I'm not using the correct term for this type of "simulated" merge (before doing final merge).

Have you tried to rebase the proposed branch with the changes from target branch of a PR?

@AlvinZhao-MSFT If you are asking whether the devs try rebasing their changes against target branch before/during PR creation?  Then I believe some do, but it's not consistent. The thought with the proposed extension process (above) of the existing pipline is to ensure that step happens every time AND a build+test run is done, all before the code merge happens (if that makes sense).

I am thinking if you would consider using git merge against the target branch into the local main branch on the pipeline agent machine. Once the code in the local repo on the agent is merged, you can proceed to test with that code without actual merge to the remote main branch then creating sim-merge branch.

@AlvinZhao-MSFT ah yes, I guess this could all be done on local, updated (merge or rebased) main with the proposed changes applied, without actually creating a separate branch. Ultimately, I'm just looking for best way to achieve that all within the same pipeline that's running on the agent, so if the build of the "simulated" merge fails, it'll invalidate the PR build check. Thx for the suggestion!

Exactly, I am also testing in my pipeline based on this design as well, but there are some errors to be resolved. If there is any progress from your side, please feel welcome to share in the answer section.

Azure DevOps already does what you want behind the scenes. When a PR is created, the first thing AzDO does is create a temporary merge commit by merging the source branch into the target branch, and tells you if there are any conflicts. You can view that temporary merge commit by using the 3-dots menu and selecting "View merge changes". The commit ID of that temporary merge is the commit you should run your tests against.
You can also view and fetch the commit ID from a command line:
git ls-remote # all branches and PRs will be listed

# Suppose the PR # is 1234

git ls-remote | grep pull | grep 1234

# the result looks like this:
f42ba4e3b25008d393bc175d864fba435636dfb6      refs/pull/1234/merge

# you can fetch that commit either with the commit ID or the ref
git fetch origin refs/pull/1234/merge
# or
git fetch origin f42ba4e3b25008d393bc175d864fba435636dfb6

Now that commit ID: f42ba4e3b25008d393bc175d864fba435636dfb6 is exactly what you need to use for your test.
Note: The temporary merge commit is automatically updated whenever you push updates to the source branch. It is not updated when the target branch is updated. If the PR is old and you know the target branch has been updated since the last merge commit was created, you can force the merge commit to be updated on the 3-dots menu of the PR by selecting "Restart merge". Typically though you would run your tests as soon as the PR is created, or new commits are pushed to the source branch, so it would always be up to date at that time.

Thanks TTT (+@bryanbcook), I figured such a branch existed at some point (as you say, for DevOps to warn of merge conflicts), but I didn't know they still hung around, which sounds VERY useful. So, if I'm understanding correctly - I could use one of those git fetch options (prob the single one with PR number, for simplicity), as a PowerShell step (like @AlvinZhao-MSFT's answer above) and then build+test as per rest of pipeline script. If so, that sounds much simpler (albeit relying on DevOps not changing how they do that!). Either way, this is great, thanks a lot, both!

@PaulNicholas the pull ref will stick around while the PR is active. We actually setup gated check-ins that monitor the pull refs and automatically start builds based on when certain folders are changed.

After confirming that this works as expected, using existing branches (negating the need to do any additional git "merge" operations) - I've now accepted this approach as the answer, thank you (again, really appreciate @AlvinZhao-MSFT's efforts at finding the previous, alternate way to achieve a similar result)

Based on the further discussions on the requirment to test with the code after the merge from source branch into the target branch of a PR, we don't seem to have to test after the actual merge into the remote main branch then creating a new sim-merge branch; instead, we may consider updating (merge or rebase) the local main branch on the agent machine of the PR validation build with the proposed changes applied.
Following that direction, I have tested with the sample PR validation pipeline below for your reference.
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
- checkout: self # During a PR validation build checkout: self will checkout the intermediate PR branch of refs/pull/{prId}/merge
  fetchDepth: 0 # Disable shallow fetch to keep the related history between branches
  persistCredentials: true

- powershell: |
    git checkout -b $(System.PullRequest.targetBranchName)
    
    Write-Host Pull from the remote $(System.PullRequest.targetBranchName) branch
    git pull origin $(System.PullRequest.targetBranchName)
    
    Write-Host Merge the changes from $(Build.SourceBranch) into current local $(System.PullRequest.targetBranchName) branch on agent
    git fetch origin $(Build.SourceBranch):refs/remotes/origin/pull-$(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)
    git merge origin/pull-$(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)
    
    tree $(Pipeline.Workspace) /F /A
  condition: eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '**/*.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'select'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '**\*.sln'

- task: VSTest@3
  inputs:
    testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
    testAssemblyVer2: |
      **\PRVSTestDemoTests.dll
      !**\*TestAdapter.dll
      !**\obj\**
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    resultsFolder: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)\TestResults'



As another benifit like what we discussed, this workflow would invalidate the PR build check, if the build of the simulated local merge failed.

Thank you @AlvinZhao-MSFT - this seems perfect for what I'm looking for.
I'm gonna try this is in a test project/repo now, but reading the code, it all makes sense - so short of that, I'm happy marking this as the answer.
Many thanks for taking the time to put this together!

Hi @PaulNicholas, thank you for your time and efforts as well. Please don't hesitate to share/edit the answer if you have better ideas. I am not so familiar with git command as Azure DevOps feature, to be honest. Happy codding and cheers!

Azure DevOps already does this.
In a build that is triggered as part of a pull-request, Azure DevOps performs a merge of your source-branch against the target-branch in a temporary branch. You can see evidence of this because a conflict between the source and target branch will prevent build validation pipelines from executing.
The temporary branch uses a naming convention of refs/pull/<pull-request-id>/merge. The branch is automatically removed when the pull-request is completed.
Although these branches do not appear in the Azure Repos user interface, you can add the following to your .git/config, which will allow you to pull down the branch to your local environment for inspection.
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/pull/*/merge:refs/remotes/origin/pull/*/merge


This is strangely similar to my answer, which was approximately 5 hrs before yours...

Yeah, I started writing my answer and then got distracted by my day job :-) I finished my answer and clicked Submit. Smart minds think alike.
